# move (transform: translate (x, y)) text (<p>) within a div making it look like it is hidden in the same div

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a div that when hovering on it, the text moves to the right. I would like to achieve some effect as if the text were lost inside the div while moving to the right.

```css
.rectangulo_categoria {
  border-radius: 34px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 195px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 8px 4px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.rectangulo_categoria:hover .texto_engranen_1 {
  transform: translate(168px, 0px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.texto_engranen_1 {
  line-height: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  pointer-events: none;
  line-height: 1;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #343434;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangulo_categoria" mdbWavesEffect>
  <p class="texto_engranen_1 p-0 m-0">Gestion Recursos de Apoyo Académico</p>
</div>
```

this is my full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/te0p2fqb/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `overflow: hidden;` on the div. Also I re-arranged your classes and removed some duplicate props.

```css
.rectangulo_categoria {
  border-radius: 34px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 195px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 8px 4px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.texto_engranen_1 {
  line-height: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: auto;
  font-weight: 400;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-out;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #343434;
}

.rectangulo_categoria:hover .texto_engranen_1 {
  transform: translate(168px, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangulo_categoria" mdbWavesEffect>
  <p class="texto_engranen_1 p-0 m-0">Gestion Recursos de Apoyo Académico</p>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
Sure check the code on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nr8x9eyz/) for aboslute solution. The main changes are that I removed the flex and its attributes, also reset the margin and padding on the `<p>`.

Comment: Can I achieve the same effect if the div has relative position and the text absolute position?

Answer (score 0):

add overflow: hidden; to your .rectangulo_categoria class

```
.rectangulo_categoria{
  border-radius: 34px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 195px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 8px 4px 10px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  overflow: hidden; // this is your solution
}
```